# Facebook Apps - Auto login within Facebook website OpenGraph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Good morning,

I am currently starting the rebuild of a Facebook app. This will be an app that can be viewed within Facebook and not an external website e.g. https://apps.facebook.com/wordswithfriends/

I was wondering how you would auto log-in a Facebook user as they are already within the Facebook site. My hunch is that because it is just a canvas (i.e. iframe) it cannot be done without a redirect by using a meta refresh e.g. top.location.href='https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=XXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/XXXXXXX/intro.php?&scope=email,user_likes,publish_stream';

Comment: What do you mean by "auto-login"? I don't really get it. You cannot bypass the permissions dialog (this would be a huge security issue). By checking if an access token is set, you can check whether a user already granted permissions to your app and you can redirect directly.

Comment: You don't need a redirect if you use the FB JS SDK - you will just make a call to the FB.login function. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/